# API Rails routes where token is part of the route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I need to   create a Ruby on Rails API where routes will look like

```
mydomain.com/api/v1/xxxxxxxx/
mydomain.com/api/v1/xxxxxxxx/messages
mydomain.com/api/v1/xxxxxxxx/authors/123/books
```

`xxxxxxxx` represent the API key and it should be picked up as a `params[:key]` or  something simmillar like`params[:api_connection_key]`

e.g `mydomain.com/api/v1/xxxxxxxx/messages` point to app/controllers/api/v1/messages_controller.rb

I'm wondering how would you design the `config/routes.rb` to achive this ? (controllers and rest of logic is fine, just routes)

no `mydomain.com/api/v1/messages?key=xxxxxxxx` is not an option and  Header authentication is out of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scope` supports dynamic segments

```
Rails.application.routes.draw

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      scope "/:key" do
        resources :messages
      end
    end
  end
  
end
```

Comment: nice! thank you very much sir. . Works beautifully `/api/v1/:key/messages`